# Finding roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

**Exercise**

Let $w, z$ are the unit roots of equation $z^5 = 1$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Prove that $(w^{21} + z^{14})^5$ is always a real number.

---

So, first I can do:

$w^{21} = w$

$z^{14} = z^4$

So then I have:

$(w + z^{4})^5$

But I'm not sure what I can do with this. I've tried using Newton's Binomial and also trying to write the roots as $e^{i(\frac{\phi + 2k\pi}{5})}$ but because the roots are not multiplied but in a sum I don't think that will be useful. Using Newton's Binomial I ended with a summatory but with different coefficient, so I wasn't able to apply the typical rule to solve these kind of exercises:

If w belongs to Gn:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} w^{i} = 0$

Comment: G5${}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: Based on the title of the question, I assume it is the group of 5th roots of unity (in the complex numbers)

Comment: Yes, G5 = group of 5th roots of unity. Sorry, maybe that notation is not standard, it's the way it's used in my university.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're off to a good start.  Note that in your simplified expression $(w+z^4)^5$, $w$ and $z^4$ could be any fifth roots of unity.  So the problem reduces to showing that the sum of two fifth roots of unity raised to the fifth power yields a real number.

So let $a$ and $b$ be any fifth roots of unity.  Note that $\bar{a}=a^4$ and $\bar{b}=b^4$.

We have $(a+b)^5= a^5 + 5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5$

Now note that $a^5=1$ and $b^5=1$.  So these terms contribute only real values to the sum.  But also $a^4b$ and $ab^4$ are conjugates. So $5a^4b+5ab^4$ is real.  Similarly, $a^3b^2$ and $a^2b^3$ are conjugates. So $10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3$ is also real.

Comment: Perhaps slightly easier, $(w+z^4)^5=w^5(1+\zeta)^5=(1+\zeta)^5$ where $\zeta=z^4w^4$ is another root of unity. Then it is even more obvious that there are conjugates in the binomial expansion.